# PyCUDA - passing a matrix by reference from python to C++ CUDA code

Tags: matrix, pass-by-reference, pycuda

I have to write in a PyCUDA function that gets two matrices Nx3 and Mx3, and return a matrix NxM, but I can't figure out how to pass by reference a matrix without knowing the number of columns.

My code basically is something like that:

```
#kernel declaration
mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void distance(int N, int M, float d1[][3], float d2[][3], float res[][M])
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y;
    float x, y, z;
    x = d2[j][0]-d1[i][0];
    y = d2[j][1]-d1[i][1];
    z = d2[j][2]-d1[i][2];
    res[i][j] = x*x + y*y + z*z;
}
""")

#load data
data1 = numpy.loadtxt("data1.txt").astype(numpy.float32) # Nx3 matrix
data2 = numpy.loadtxt("data2.txt").astype(numpy.float32) # Mx3 matrix
N=data1.shape[0]
M=data2.shape[0]
res = numpy.zeros([N,M]).astype(numpy.float32) # NxM matrix

#invoke kernel
dist_gpu = mod.get_function("distance")
dist_gpu(cuda.In(numpy.int32(N)), cuda.In(numpy.int32(M)), cuda.In(data1), cuda.In(data2), cuda.Out(res), block=(N,M,1))

#save data
numpy.savetxt("results.txt", res)
```

Compiling this I receive an error:

```
kernel.cu(3): error: a parameter is not allowed
```

that is, I cannot use M as the number of columns for res[][] in the declaretion of the function. I cannot either left the number of columns undeclared...

I need a matrix NxM as an output, but I can't figure out how to do this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pitched linear memory access inside the kernel, that is how `ndarray` and `gpuarray` store data internally, and PyCUDA will pass a pointer to the data in gpu memory allocated for a `gpuarray` when it is supplied as a argument to a PyCUDA kernel. So (if I understand what you are trying to do) your kernel should be written as something like:

```
__device__ unsigned int idx2d(int i, int j, int lda)
{
    return j + i*lda;
}

__global__ void distance(int N, int M, float *d1, float *d2, float *res)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
    float x, y, z;
    x = d2[idx2d(j,0,3)]-d1[idx2d(i,0,3)];
    y = d2[idx2d(j,1,3)]-d1[idx2d(i,1,3)];
    z = d2[idx2d(j,2,3)]-d1[idx2d(i,2,3)];

    res[idx2d(i,j,N)] = x*x + y*y + z*z;
}
```

Here I have assumed the `numpy` default row major ordering in defining the `idx2d` helper function. There are still problems with the Python side of the code you posted, but I guess you know that already.

---

**EDIT**: Here is a complete working repro case based of the code posted in your question. Note that it only uses a single block (like the original), so be mindful of block and grid dimensions when trying to run it on anything other than trivially small cases.

```
import numpy as np
from pycuda import compiler, driver
from pycuda import autoinit

#kernel declaration
mod = compiler.SourceModule("""
__device__ unsigned int idx2d(int i, int j, int lda)
{
    return j + i*lda;
}

__global__ void distance(int N, int M, float *d1, float *d2, float *res)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
    float x, y, z;
    x = d2[idx2d(j,0,3)]-d1[idx2d(i,0,3)];
    y = d2[idx2d(j,1,3)]-d1[idx2d(i,1,3)];
    z = d2[idx2d(j,2,3)]-d1[idx2d(i,2,3)];

    res[idx2d(i,j,N)] = x*x + y*y + z*z;
}
""")

#make data
data1 = np.random.uniform(size=18).astype(np.float32).reshape(-1,3)
data2 = np.random.uniform(size=12).astype(np.float32).reshape(-1,3)
N=data1.shape[0]
M=data2.shape[0]
res = np.zeros([N,M]).astype(np.float32) # NxM matrix

#invoke kernel
dist_gpu = mod.get_function("distance")
dist_gpu(np.int32(N), np.int32(M), driver.In(data1), driver.In(data2), \
        driver.Out(res), block=(N,M,1), grid=(1,1))

print res
```

Comment: I tried your solution but something weird happened, I received the error `LaunchError: cuCtxSynchronize failed: launch failed` when I tried to copy **res** back to the python code, using both _cuda.Out()_ both _cuda.memcpy_dtoh()_. I tracked down the error and it seems to originate in the idx2d function, particularly when multiplying **i** and **lda**. Instead
`return j + i*10;`
works perfectly (10 is the actual number of points in data2, in my examples).
Why my code is doing this to me? :(

Comment: I can't answer that - it is your code. I have edited my answer into a complete working example and confirmed it runs with PyCUDA 0.94.2 and CUDA 3.2 on a Fermi card hosted in a 64 bit linux host. That is the best I can do.

Comment: Thanks to your example, I found my error! I was using _driver.In()_ to pass **M*** in the kernel, I thought it worked with every variable - not only arrays (it's my first script in pycuda...). Now it's working, thank you very much!